# jquery "empty" changes the scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am updating content with ajax call from server.
after the update, i empty the wrapper div, that contains the data, and fill it again with the new data.
so far so good.
the problem is - that on a

```
$('#MessagesContainer').empty();
```

method - the scrollbar changes back up.
so if someione want to add data and he is in the bottom of the page, the scroll goes back up.

this action makes sense, but for this particular action i want to avoid it since it's not so "user-friendly".

Comment: Why do you have to empty the container, why not just replace with $('#MessagesContainer').html(newContent); ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, thanks for your answers.
use .html() would probably be better than .empty() and re-append the data.
but, the thing is that for my implementation that is not possible.

so what i did is implemented

```
.RemoveAfter(x) function
```

that remove all the elements after index 'x' in the collection and then append data from this 'x' index. that did the trick. the scrollbar stays where it is. it's not 100% percent user-friendly since it make some of the data disappear for a milisecond and then it comes back, but at this currently point, it's the best i could think of.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$('#MessagesContainer').html('');` 
This may work.

Answer (score 0):

If the container you are emptying is almost all the content in the site that behaviour makes sense since for a millisecond the browser doesnt need a scrollbar.

Try just append a new container with the new messages and then remove the old one, in that way the user wont have any changes to the scroll state. Howere if the user was looking at something below the message container and there are more messages now than before the user might have to scroll down some.

Answer (score 0):

Give you #messagecontainer a height with css. or depending on the layout add a second div with a min-height inside the scrolling div and then update the content of the inner div.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `height` or `min-height` css property to the `#MessagesContainer` `div` this will mean that even when the contents are empty it still maintains a reasonable height on the page - this will keep the srollbar present